# VPS Server OS differences

Tags: linux, vps, http, windows, xml

I have two VPS servers. one of them is running Linux and the other is Windows one. I've uploaded same file to their public_html folders and could see them in my browser via static IP address of each one like `http://178.63.165.178/getorder/file.xml` and `http://178.63.165.178/getorder/file.xml`.

On the other side there is a device called **SMSPrinter** that configured to read those XML files using GPRS and need static IP address to reach destination server. unfortunately this device can only read file from windows server and could not reach the file on Linux server.

There is no note in this device manual suggesting Windows server or specific OS! I've also set file permission on Linux server to 777 to have no limitation. what could be the cause of our problem?

**Thanks.**

Comment: Are you sure your checking both servers? The IP's you gave us are the same.

Comment: Yes I am sure. those address were just for example. in real situation I am sure.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, there is no reason it would care which web server is serving the content. There is something different between the two that is preventing SMSPrinter from retrieving the page. Sadly there just isn't enough information to give an answer on how to fix it. Here are some things I'd start troubleshooting with.

I'd start pay making sure you are able to view both feeds on a phone that is on the same service provider you are using the GPRS printer with. This will make sure the provider isn't blocking the IP and also make sure that the linux server is blocking anything.

Then I'd start with checking the HTTP headers, and make sure the are similar. Mainly the content-type and content-length as that might mess with the printer.

Another thought is to make sure the SMSPrinter isn't configured to listen to any type of blacklist or has any settings that might be blocking the IP of the linux server.

Update - 7/3/12 - I used `the curl -I` command on each (based on the information you provided) And the Content-Length of the linux server is 528 and the Content-Length of the Windows Server is 1178; Looks like the linux server is using mod_gzip or mod_deflate. Try turning that off and see where that gets you.

Comment: Here is my HTTP header report: http://garson.ir/temp/linux.txt and http://garson.ir/temp/windows.txt

Comment: Thanks, I've Updated my answer with more ideas. That's the only other thing I can think of right now.